# How to create column name with dot(".") in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a table in PostgreSQL, but I am getting an error 
`create table bond ([Coupon.Type] varchar(35),[Coupon.Index] varchar(35),[Tranche.1] varchar(35),[Tranche.2] varchar(35))` I have tried removing the "[" and as `Coupon.Type`,also `"Coupon.Type"` but nothing works.

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: Room varchar(35),(Coupon.Type) varchar(35),[Coupon.Index] va...`

Comment: @AlexK. I have used the quotes but its not working

Answer (score 12):

This will work

```
create table bond 
( 
   "Coupon.Type" varchar(35)
  ,"Coupon.Index" varchar(35)
  ,"Tranche.1" varchar(35)
  ,"Tranche.2" varchar(35)
)
```

Comment: It worked, thank you @Anuraag

Comment: Double quotes also works when selecting a column with a dot.